# How can I make preg_match_all array

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

I have this:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

When I `echo $text` I get this:

```
ggg #hhh #ddd ggg hhhrr ggg #ttt
```

When I do this:

```
$val = preg_match_all("/#\w+/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I get

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => #hhh [1] => #ddd [2] => #ttt ) )
```

But I want output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => #hhh [1] => #ddd [2] => #ttt )
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first (zeroth) item from the array by changing this:

```
print_r($matches);
```

To this:

```
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use named groups.

```
$val = preg_match_all("/(?P<myLabel>#\w+)/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches['myLabel']);
```